# How to show PHP Duplicate Entry error message on current page

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am creating a signup form for a website I am developing. I am using PHP to insert the form into my database. I have the useremail set as a Unique Key in my database. When I type in an email that already exists in my database it brings me to a blank page with this

> error message: Duplicate entry '' for key 'email_2'

How can I get this message to show up above the form, without clearing the form? In the code the "SERVER ERROR" and "BOTH FIELDS MUST BE COMPLETE" text is showing up in the correct place. How can I make the Duplicate entry error show up in the same way?

Here is the PHP code I currently have. Please note I am successfully connecting to my database, but did not include the code here.

```
$firstName  = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastName  = $_POST['lastname'];
$useremail  = $_POST['useremail'];
$password  = $_POST['password'];
$gender  = $_POST['gender'];
$birthday  = $_POST['birthday'];
$sqlDate = date('Y-m-d');

if (     $firstName!=''&&$lastName!=''&&$useremail!=''&&$password!=''&&$gender!=''&&$birthday!='')
{
   $sql = "INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, email, password, gender, birthday) VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$useremail', '$password', '$gender', '$birthday')";

   $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   if($res)
   {  

 header('location: http://myticapp.com/thankyou.php?useremail='.$useremail);
   }
   else
   {

 echo"<center><div class=\"denied\">SERVER ERROR</div></center>";
   }

}
else if(!empty($_POST))
{
  echo"<center><div class=\"denied\">BOTH FIELDS MUST BE COMPLETE</div>    </center>";
}
```

Here is the Form Code:

```
  `<form action="#" method="POST" class="signupform">
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required/>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="useremail" placeholder="Email" required/>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="gender" placeholder="Gender" required/>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="birthday" placeholder="Birthday (YYYY-MM-DD)" required/>
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="button buttonhover"/>
                    </form>`
```

Comment: it seems the email you want to insert already exist in database and email is an unique field .

Comment: I want to show a message on the current form page that says "email already exists". The email is already set as a unique field in my database. I just am having trouble showing the message on the same.

Comment: when you are insert the email, before inserting again search it on database, if it is there, so the message and if not insert it . this is the logic part of your need according me, there are several way to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run check query before inserting data.

```
<?
$firstName  = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastName  = $_POST['lastname'];
$useremail  = $_POST['useremail'];
$password  = $_POST['password'];
$gender  = $_POST['gender'];
$birthday  = $_POST['birthday'];
$sqlDate = date('Y-m-d');

$useremail = mysql_escape_string($useremail);
$duplicate = false;

try {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM user WHERE email = '$useremail'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    if ($data['count'] > 0) {
        echo '<center>EMAIL ALREADY IN USE</center>';
        $duplicate = true;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {

}

if (     $firstName!=''&&$lastName!=''&&$useremail!=''&&$password!=''&&$gender!=''&&$birthday!=''&&$duplicate==false)
{

   try
   {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, email, password, gender, birthday) VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$useremail', '$password', '$gender', '$birthday')";
        $res = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
       echo "<center><div class=\"denied\">",  $e->getMessage(), "</div></center>";

    }


  if(isset($res))
   {  
      header('location: http://myticapp.com/thankyou.php?useremail='.$useremail);
   }
   else
   {

 echo"<center><div class=\"denied\">SERVER ERROR</div></center>";
   }

}
else if(!empty($_POST))
{
  echo"<center><div class=\"denied\">BOTH FIELDS MUST BE COMPLETE</div>    </center>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Would you mind adding this statement in the code I have above? I tried putting it in but it broke the php page. I am not sure how to add this to the code I already have.

Comment: When I tried this it just gives me the "Email Already In Use" text and no form. Is there a way to have the message appear on top of the page and still have the rest of the page showing, instead of clearing everything out and just showing the message?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @EchoUA.COM answer for handle case   you try to insert an already existing email you can also try something like this:

```
$firstName  = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastName  = $_POST['lastname'];
$useremail  = $_POST['useremail'];
$password  = $_POST['password'];
$gender  = $_POST['gender'];
$birthday  = $_POST['birthday'];
$sqlDate = date('Y-m-d');

if (     $firstName!=''&&$lastName!=''&&$useremail!=''&&$password!=''&&$gender!=''&&$birthday!='')
{

   try
   {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, email, password, gender, birthday) VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$useremail', '$password', '$gender', '$birthday')";
        $res = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
       echo "<center><div class=\"denied\">",  $e->getMessage(), "</div></center>";

    }


  if(isset($res))
   {  
      header('location: http://myticapp.com/thankyou.php?useremail='.$useremail);
   }
   else
   {

 echo"<center><div class=\"denied\">SERVER ERROR</div></center>";
   }

}
else if(!empty($_POST))
{
  echo"<center><div class=\"denied\">BOTH FIELDS MUST BE COMPLETE</div>    </center>";
}
```

Basically you try to execute the insert query, if it is not successful you will catch the error, echo it and then the rest of your code will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried the code you provided, but it takes me to the successful submit page even if the email already exists, without showing an error message.

Comment: sorry my bad, try now

Answer (score -1):

```
    $email                 = ($_POST['email']);   
    $email_duplicate_error = ("SELECT email FROM users WHERE '{$email}' == 
    email");
    if($email_duplicate_error){
     //Your message .. .
     $previous = "<script>window.history.go(-1);</script>";
     echo $previous;
```

}

Comment: This question already contains multiple answers and an accepted answer. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answers? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.